# UITableView changes height when reloaded

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a weird issue going on with my `UITableView`. Even though I have specified a height for it in IB, when it is reloaded, sometimes the height changes -- usually increasing. This causes the bottom of the table to be obscured by other view elements, and makes it impossible to scroll to very bottom row.

Why does the table size change by itself?

There is a products view, where the user selects a bunch of products to add to their order. They then tap a button to review their order. the product view passes the products information to the next view, lets call it the cart view and loads it. This is the cart view:

The View:
[image]

The cart view loads the products into the table, it then submits a request to the server to validate the order. The server responds with errors (like not enough inventory available for a product) and any applicable discounts. The table is then reloaded with this information included (the errors  appear inside the cells and the discount items are added as new cells).

Relevant Code From the Cart View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (!self.initialized) {
        [self saveOrderOnFirstLoad];
    }
}

- (void)saveOrderOnFirstLoad {
    if ([helper isOrderReadyForSubmission:self.coreDataOrder]) {
        self.coreDataOrder.status = @"pending";
        [[CoreDataUtil sharedManager] saveObjects];
        NSDictionary *parameters = [self.coreDataOrder asJSONReqParameter];
        //todo should we keep completed orders, complete? Or should we update status to pending if they go to cart view, even if they did not make any changes?
        NSString *method = [self.coreDataOrder.orderId intValue] > 0 ? @"PUT" : @"POST";
        NSString *url = [self.coreDataOrder.orderId intValue] == 0 ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@", kDBORDER, kAuthToken, self.authToken] : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:kDBORDEREDITS([self.coreDataOrder.orderId intValue])], kAuthToken, self.authToken];
        void (^successBlock)(NSURLRequest *, NSHTTPURLResponse *, id) = ^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id json) {
            self.savedOrder = [self loadJson:json];
            self.unsavedChangesPresent = NO;
        };
        void(^failureBlock)(NSURLRequest *, NSHTTPURLResponse *, NSError *, id) = ^(NSURLRequest *req, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id json) {
            if (json) {
                [self loadJson:json];
            }
        };
        [helper sendRequest:method url:url parameters:parameters successBlock:successBlock failureBlock:failureBlock view:self.view loadingText:@"Submitting order"];
    }
    self.initialized = YES;
}

- (AnOrder *)loadJson:(id)json {
    AnOrder *anOrder = [[AnOrder alloc] initWithJSONFromServer:(NSDictionary *) json];
    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:self.coreDataOrder];//delete existing core data representation
    self.coreDataOrder = [helper createCoreDataCopyOfOrder:anOrder customer:self.customer loggedInVendorId:self.loggedInVendorId loggedInVendorGroupId:self.loggedInVendorGroupId managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];//create fresh new core data representation
    [[CoreDataUtil sharedManager] saveObjects];
    [self refreshView];
    return anOrder;
}

- (void)refreshView {
    self.productsInCart = [helper sortProductsByinvtId:[self.coreDataOrder productIds]];
    self.discountsInCart = [helper sortDiscountsByLineItemId:[self.coreDataOrder discountLineItemIds]];
    [self.productsUITableView reloadData];
    [self updateTotals];
}
```

The height of the table set in IB is 459.
[image]

When I debug, I find that when the table is loaded the first time, the debugger shows the height of the table to be 459. But when it is loaded again (after response is received from the server, the height is no longer 459):
[image]

And this seems to happen only when there is a large number of cells in the table.

**[UPDATE]**
The issue turned out to be that I had autolayout turned on on the table while it was turned off on its parent view. Once I turned autolayout on for the parent view, the height of the table stayed constant and I could scroll to the bottom row.

Comment: Please share some code. It's hard to diagnose a problem without looking at the possible culprits.

Comment: It will be helpful if you add some code from your project how you reload your data so I can help you.

Comment: I will try to share the code. But I feel the issue is independent. There are a lot of SO questions regarding ppl not being able to scroll to bottom of a table. And it all seems to boil down to the fact that the UITableView height seems to change after cells are added or removed. My question is simply why does the height change when it has been explicitly set in IB.

Comment: And why was this question voted to be closed as off topic? It is very much related to programming!

Comment: Maybe you are using AutoLayout in the IB and you dont want it?

Comment: UITableView does not change it's height, which is why people with knowledge of UITableView are asking for code.

Comment: The specific close reason that was chosen here is "Off Topic: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: If you think it's silly that this is under the "Off Topic" heading, well, [so do a lot of other people](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/shouldnt-off-topic-be-only-about-off-topic).

Comment: i am in the process of editing the question and adding the code.

Comment: Added code as requested.

Comment: I think the problem is on your nib AutoLayout is enabled. That's why it is not accepting your height :)

Comment: @kkocabiyik I just found that out myself. The tableview was set to use autolayout, but the parent view was not. When I turned on autolayout on the parent, it started working right.

Comment: @kkocabiyik I am going to read up on autolayout, but is one of the lessons that one should not mix autolayout elements with non-autolayout ones? And pl post your comment as answer, so you can get the points.

Comment: @septerr No, you can mix auto-layout and manual layout fine as long as you know what you're doing.  There is discussion in the docs about how to safely combine them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is on your nib AutoLayout is enabled. That's why it is not accepting your height. Once you use auto layout all of the modification in the subviews will be ignored. If you are going with non-autolayouts you should go for all of your views.